# Python - installing libraries from github

Tags: python, github, pip

I am trying to work with the newest Azure SDK library. I originally installed the libraries using PIP and haven't had any issues. Found a newer feature that was released but I didn't have it available in my library. So I tried to re-install the libraries via PIP. No good... Then I went through the process of cloning the repo from Github and then installing it from source. It went through without errors, but the new features weren't available to my code.

Digging into the downloaded code, I can see the feature is the code I pulled from Github but it is just not getting installed to where Python can see it. It seems that when running setup.py, the installation is happening somewhere else. I'm not sure what to do at this point or what the best way to make sure I am running the most recent code.

Should I somehow remove everything that PIP installed originally? (not sure how to do that) or do I need to point python to where the libraries are? (concerned that there will be confusion since there is currently two of everything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just pip install straight from github.

```
pip uninstall <package-name>

pip install git+<link-to-repo.git>
```

Comment: That throws errors.error: error in 'egg_base' option: 'pip-egg-info' does not exist or is not a directory. I have downloaded the repo and ran the setup.py without issues, it just doesn't seem to be installed in the correct place.