# Best practices for installing and using python libraries that are not available through pip or tarball distributions

Tags: python, git, pip, pypi

What is the best practice for installing Python libraries that are available on a VCS, but are not maintained as pip installable packages?

So far I've found lots of solutions that suggest just [installing directly from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58423113/python-installing-libraries-from-github), but those all appear to require that the maintainer has packaged for a pip install. There's also the [option of installing from tarballs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021133/offline-installation-of-dependant-python-modules-without-pip), but in this case, the maintainer does not offer an installable tarball.

There are several attempts on [pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=epd&o=) to release this, but they are all out of date or have issues of one kind or another.

The library in question is for working with [E-Paper displays from waveshare](https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper). The libraries I'd like to use are buried several [directories deep](https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper/tree/master/RaspberryPi%26JetsonNano/python/lib/waveshare_epd) within the git repository. To make things worse, the project is released without a license.txt, but does have a [generic license text within each library file](https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper/blob/master/RaspberryPi%26JetsonNano/python/lib/waveshare_epd/epd2in7b.py). The license text appears to grant a wide permission to include the libraries into any type of project (see the text below).

I've come up with a few options for dealing with this, but I hope there's something better:

1. Copy the libraries into the project

   Issues:

   - libraries get stale
   - there's no easy way to update them except for manually copying into the project
2. Repackage the libraries and upload to pip

   Issues:

   - I now need to maintain the pypi projects
   - They end up stale and with issues exactly like the ones I've found so far

Comment: What about copying/filtering the subdirectory into your own private Git repo and installing from there?

Comment: I can definitely copy the required subdir into my own repo. Is there a sane way to keep that copy fresh without manually pulling and recopying? I can script that, but it all feels like a huge kludge and doesn't make the project easy to deploy in the future.

Comment: The code you've linked to is not really production quality... So if you're really going to deploy that project in a production environment you should have someone maintain that copied library anyways.

Comment: It's for a home project, but one I can see using over and over again. I suppose I can add a line in the README.md that clues me in to update the libraries manually or with a script. Is this "good practice?" Or, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `setup.py` and so it should be possible to install the project with the following command:

```
pip install -e 'git+https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper.git#egg=waveshare-epd&subdirectory=RaspberryPi&JetsonNano/python'
```

But it fails since there is an ampersand (`&`) in the directory name. If it were possible to somehow escape that character, it would probably work.

Comment: I had no idea that you could specify sub directories like that! That's a huge side-win. Thanks for teaching me that.

Comment: I cloned the Repo and renamed the directory to remove the offending "&", but pip still has issues. It looks like it expects there to be a setup.py higher up in the tree: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/src/slimpi_epd/src/waveshare-epd/setup.py' Any other ideas?

Comment: `$ pip3 install -e git+https://github.com/txoof/e-Paper.git#egg=waveshare-epd&subdirectory=RaspberryPi_and_JetsonNano/python` That does clone the repo into ~/src/waveshare-epd, but errors out ultimately with: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/src/waveshare-epd/setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /home/pi/src/waveshare-epd/`

Comment: Aaand. I'm an idiot. I forgot the quotes! Thanks for your help. This might be a good middle-of-the-road solution.

Comment: If I were you, I would ask the maintainers of the project to fix the name of the folder.

Comment: I just did that. That would simplify things tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few variants of url encoding, etc., but couldn't get it to go directly from pip... so I did the following instead:

```
git clone https://github.com/waveshare/e-Paper
cd e-Paper/RaspberryPi\&JetsonNano/
pip3 install -e .
```

→
`Successfully installed waveshare-epd` :D